# How to pause flutter video(video_player plugin) when navigating from page to another

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I'm using flutter video_player(https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/video_player) plugin to play videos. But When I navigate from one page to another in flutter the video is still playing. I'm having the same problem when playing music from any other app(eg: playing music from notification while flutter video is playing). How can I pause it?

Comment: HI,I have same issue to pause the video in Listview,Like instagram and facebook I have a video in Listview builder,How to check the visibility index to play video and pause to remain,Please give me some suggestion.

Answer (score 37):

**Edit:**
**Second option:**
So I came up with another solution. [`VisibilityDetector`](https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector)
is a `Widget' that can wrap any other Widget and notify when the visible area of the widget changed.

```
VisibilityDetector(
   key: Key("unique key"),
   onVisibilityChanged: (VisibilityInfo info) {
       debugPrint("${info.visibleFraction} of my widget is visible");
       if(info.visibleFraction == 0){
           videoPlayerController.pause();
       }
       else{
           videoPlayerController.play();
       }
   },
   child: VideoPlayer());
)
```

---

**First Option:**
By using the `RouteObserver` and `RouteAware` your widget will be informed whenever another screen is pushed on top of it, or it's popped back on top.

First, you need to add a `RouteObserver` to `MaterialApp` or your `Navigator`.

```
RouteObserver<PageRoute> routeObserver = RouteObserver<PageRoute>();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      navigatorObservers: [routeObserver], //HERE
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

Then you must add the `RouteAware` mixin to your widget, and subscribe it to the `RouteObserver`.

```
class VideoPlayerItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final File file;

  VideoPlayerItem(this.file);

  @override
  _VideoPlayerItemState createState() => _VideoPlayerItemState();
}

class _VideoPlayerItemState extends State<VideoPlayerItem> with RouteAware {

  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(widget.file);
    _videoPlayerController.initialize().then((_) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
        _videoPlayerController.play();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context));//Subscribe it here
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  /// Called when the current route has been popped off.
  @override
  void didPop() {
    print("didPop");
    super.didPop();
  }

  /// Called when the top route has been popped off, and the current route
  /// shows up.
  @override
  void didPopNext() {
    print("didPopNext");
    _videoPlayerController.play();
    super.didPopNext();
  }

  /// Called when the current route has been pushed.
  @override
  void didPush() { 
    print("didPush");
    super.didPush();
  }

  /// Called when a new route has been pushed, and the current route is no
  /// longer visible.
  @override
  void didPushNext() {
    print("didPushNext");
    _videoPlayerController.pause();
    super.didPushNext();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _videoPlayerController?.value?.initialized ?? false
        ? AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
            child: VideoPlayer(_videoPlayerController),
          )
        : Container();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    routeObserver.unsubscribe(this); //Don't forget to unsubscribe it!!!!!!
    super.dispose();
    _videoPlayerController.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: HI,I have same issue to pause the video in Listview,Like instagram and facebook I have a video in Listview builder,How to check the visibility index to play video and pause to remain,Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: @ShangariC The above solutions didn't satisfy your problem?

Comment: I used visibility detector it works well when I have a video post in randomly at the time.Whereas if I have all post with video then it returns 1.0 for every index so its playing all at once.please give me some suggestion.

Comment: @ShangariC I faced this problem too and solved it by reading [this artice](https://www.didierboelens.com/2019/05/is-a-widget-inside-a-scrollable-visible). It needs a little modification but I'm sure you can figure it out cause it's very close to the final solution. This will check visible items in a limited area. By adjusting the area you can assure that only one video is playing

Comment: Okay sure I will read that article,Thanks for your valuable reply

Comment: The above article works well,But In my app I have 3 Listview in Column,but I have a video post available in 3rd Listview is it possible to achieve that logic here.

Comment: @ShangariC 99.9% of times you can show all you want in just a `ListView`. Is there any specific reason that you don't merge your `ListView`s into a one?

Comment: I have a different section in singlechildscrollview 1)verticle list view with some data  2)verticle list view with some data  3)Horizontal list view with post like facebook this list view only contains video post,All I have embed in single scrollview I am confused to get a visible index for third section onwards.

Comment: this answer was very helpful to me - as I had list of videos and was facing race conditions many a times... if you are having list of videos, set autoinitialize to false , autoplay to false and then 

_videoPlayerController.initialize().then((_) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
        _videoPlayerController.play();
      }
    });

Comment: This is working perfectly. If anyone using the bottom navigation, then probably you need both first and second approach.

Answer (score 1):

You have - `VideoPlayerController _controller;`

Before Navigating to other screen -

```
 _controller.pause();  // add this
Navigator.push(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => NextPage()));
```

OR

if it's a Stateful widget then you can override - `dispose()` method.

```
@override
  void dispose() {
   super.dispose();
   _controller.pause();
  }
```

Comment: If I'm navigating to 5 diff pages then I have to do this on each navigation, which might not be a good solution.

Comment: are you playing video on each pages .? it should be done from the screen that is playing video only.

Comment: Nope, I have a page where there are multiple videos in a list. Now on this page, there are different tabs and buttons which navigate me to different pages.

Comment: then from this page before navigation push - add = `_controller.pause();` or if its a Stateful Widget. then you can add it in dispose() method also.

Comment: The disposed method is called when this object is removed from the tree permanently. I've tried that, it's not working.

Comment: dispose will happen when the object is going to get removed....it won't work in this case..

Comment: I think this is the best answer, according to KISS. It's simple, but effective. If you don't want to repeat yourself for multiple calls to `Navigator.push()`, then you can wrap both operations in one function.

Comment: Just one suggestion: I think `dispose()` should actually call `_controller.dispose()` to release any resources.

Answer (score -2):

Simple and its work for me, I get this from `chewie` example code: https://pub.dev/packages/chewie/example

Just on the onTap/onPressed use setState and in this setState make videoController.pause or dispose, whatever you want.

```
 onTap:() {
        setState(() {
          widget.videoController.pause();
          Navigator.of(context)
              .pushNamed(YOUR-NAVIGATION-PAGE-NAME);
        });
      },
```